# Open a movie with VLC from command line via SSH

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, vlc-media-player

I have a linux machine connected to the tv and being the lazy person I am, I would like to sit on my laptop, SSH into the linux machine and play a movie in full screen. I've tried running the command:

```
vlc -f perfectly-legal-file.mp4
```

This just runs vlc media player inside the terminal (which is pretty cool) but I'm trying to get it to run on the TV.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Should be able to do this by first setting the $DISPLAY environment variable.

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ vlc -f file.mp4
```

Comment: I see only Video, audio is NOT playing, how to mention audio channel.